# Should I have different method calls for my RESTful API?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm writing a web application on using Express. It has a RESTful API. The authentication schemes are different for the web interface and the RESTful API. Now I have something like this. The following code has the auth mechanisms stripped off.

**problem.js**

```
// Web
exports.list = function(req, res) {
  listProblems(function(err, problems) {
    if(err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      res.render('problems', { title: 'Problems', problems: problems });
    }
  });
};

// REST API
exports.apiList = function(req, res) {
  listProblems(function(err, problems) {
    if(err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      res.json(problems);
    }
  });
};

// Named function to query MongoDB, common to both Web and REST
function listProblems(callback) {
  var query = Problem.find().select(DEFAULT_FIELDS);
  query.exec(callback);
};
```

Routes in **app.js**

```
app.get('/problems', problem.list);
app.get('/api/v1/problems', problem.apiList);
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing the right thing. Please let me know. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This is perfectly acceptable.  Typically the rest api is called after the front end loads,  as you have it set up by w,  you may not need both.  If you want to update the front end code after render,  having the backend rest api would be helpful.

Comment: What is the question exactly?  What part of what you are doing are you worried about?

Comment: @Emmentaler, I am worried about two different methods `list` and `apiList`. Is it normal to have both?

Comment: @KellyJAndrews, both have different authentication schemes. When that's the case, am I doing the right thing?

Comment: It depends on what you want to accomplish,  but the separate Auth is Ok too.  It really depends on if you need two separate points of entry.

Comment: I get it.  I use a a similar path structure for this very reason.  If you want I can share what I do.  I have had the same issue AND I had to deal with secure vs unsecure as well as authorized vs unauth.

Comment: @KellyJAndrews, should I use a different controller for the REST API? For the sake of modularity?

Comment: @Emmentaler, please share what you have, it would be extremely helpful. This is my first app using Node.js

Comment: It's a question of what your doing.  I suppose it's possible to consolidate some of the code.  It's just how you decide to architect.  Make it the smallest amount of code possible to accomplish everything you need to do.

Comment: @KellyJAndrews, is it the express-mongodb-rest repo?

Comment: Yeah.  It's not really doing what you are with the two Auth paths.  It's Ok,  but probably has holes.

Comment: @KellyJAndrews, yeah I saw that ;)

Comment: You may consider using [content negotiation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.format) so you can fold both web and REST into one controller, but that requires the consuming clients to support it too.

Comment: I wrote an answer up but I am now thinking I still do not know the question.  You definitely want a separate call chain for your service layer.  I only serve static content for html since server rendering is so expensive in terms of bandwidth delivery costs - especially to mobile but also it is incompatible with phonegap type development.

Comment: I would take a look at the MEAN stack.  http://blog.mongodb.org/post/49262866911/the-mean-stack-mongodb-expressjs-angularjs-and